# Need to convert text to lookup field

Tags: 2010, list, import

I am inputting a list in Sharepoint that has a lookup to it. For example I have all the client data in excel, I need to import this in Sharepoint and then convert the client association from a multi line text or single line txt to lookup.

Example client A has three subcompanies called Client B and Client C and Client D

I have brought these three sub company names in a text field that I would like to use to populate a lookup field that will show under client A. A relates to company etc.

I have tried doing this through the access database and other import methods and seem to be stumped.

I would manually do the connections myself however the list is over 9000 and there are more than one field of this nature that will need to reference other columns and lists on the site.

Answer (score 2):

I think most in this scenario import the values as palin text and create their choice columns with the proper values.  Then they arrange the text and choice fields beside each other in a view and toggle over to datasheet voew and do a copy/paste, then delete the text colummn.